# Как пройти авторизацию в spring boot REST API из REST client'a?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Есть 2 приложения:
Первое приложение представляет собой REST API, работа с которым осуществляется через второе приложение с помощью RestTemplate (получение списка юзеров, добавление/редактирование/удаление).

В REST API я добавил Spring security и написал кастомный UserDetailsService, в котором 1 единственный метод findByUsername(username).

Вопрос: как я могу авторизовываться через второе (клиентское) приложение в первом?
Напрямую по адресу localhost:8080/login авторизация проходит.
Но мне нужно авторизоваться через клиентское приложение, которое запускается на localhost:8090, чтобы получить список юзеров (если я админ) или попасть на страницу авторизовавшегося юзера.

Answer (score 0):

Например, настроить проксирование через nginx. Сайт будет работать на 80 порту, все его запросы будут проксироваться nginx-ом на 8090 порт. А запросы непосредственно касающиеся авторизации nginx будет заворачивать на 8080 порт

Comment: А через basic authentication или httpClient возможно? :)

Comment: Я предполагал, что REST API это некий серверный компонент, предоставляющий некий АПИ. Второе приложение - это ВЕБ. Или не так ? Давайте еще раз проясним ) Авторизация происходит на клиенте ? То есть из браузера ?  И есть ли смысл "бить" эти части на два приложения ? Если РЕСТ АПИ действительно необходим как отдельный компонент, а админка - ВЕБ, то обычно , чтобы не столкнуться с CORS, ставится фронт-сервер, например упомянутый nginx, и на нем уже разруливаются все проксирования. В этом случае для веб-приложения абсолютно не важно, где находится АПИ (это сконфигурино на фронт-сервере)